# Python - Make a GUI for an existing script

Tags: python, user-interface, command-line

I use a certain Python script often, and it is quite laborious to constantly enter the arguments I want. I am not an expert in Python, and it is not my script. I do know a few languages though such as C and Java, so if I need to learn Python so be it. What is the easiest way? Here is the script: https://github.com/michthom/MIDI-to-CNC.

Comment: You should google search for Python GUI, there's a wiki page soley for that purpose with plenty of ways to make a GUI.

Comment: Your question sounds more like "do this for me" than it sounds like "how do I do this?" - you are going to get downvoted for this, a lot, and I doubt you will get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you say you know Java, why not write a Java program that provides the GUI, and then runs the python script? I'm pretty sure Java can run external programs